# Press and Hold Mouse to Generate Multiple Clicks with time interval

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, performance, svg

```js
console.clear();
document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => console.log("Stop"))
// Keyboard keys
document.addEventListener('mousedown', e => console.log("Hold ") )
```

```html
Please Click on This Blank Space to simulate the mouseup and mousedown event.

Have a great day !!
```

```js
let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
// paths is an html collection of all paths;
// attach event listeners to each path;
for (let i=0; i<paths.length; i++) {
  paths[i].addEventListener('click', event => console.log(event.target.dataset.key));
}
```

```html
<div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="800pt" height="600pt" viewBox="0 0 800 600 " id="svg1">
      <g enable-background="new">
        <path data-key="Line_1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 244.34 586.6 "/>
        <path data-key="Line_2" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 124.34 545.57 L 144.34 546.6 "/>
        <path data-key="Line_3" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 174.34 545.57 L 204.34 546.6 "/>            
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Above code when the 3 lines are clicked, it will output which lines are clicked with its id. In order to increase user-friendliness, I have this idea of implementing a **feature**, when the **mouse is pressed and hold**, it will **keep on clicking on the cursor with of course, some time interval to prevent lagginess**, which means **if the cursor is hovered over those 3 lines, it will actually clicked on them without user having to click each of the lines multiple times**, and w**hen the mouse is released, it will stop the clicking on the cursor** which means it will not be clicking on the lines anymore. And then, I can find the **unique of the Lines array** generated from the clicking to see which Lines are selected using the **mouse press and hold functionality** which is pretty cool :). May I know how to achieve this?  I will appreciate any help I can get :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [Document.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) to get an element at some position. The position comes from an object that is updated each time the mouse is moving. The setInterval() function will call the function elementFromMousePosition() will console.log the key if the element has one.

The interval is stopped either if the mouse is up or leaves the SVG.

```js
const svg1 = document.getElementById('svg1');
let interval;
let mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

const elementFromMousePosition = () => {
  let elm = document.elementFromPoint(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  if(elm.dataset.key) console.log(elm.dataset.key);
};

svg1.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  mouse.x = e.clientX;
  mouse.y = e.clientY;
});

svg1.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  interval = setInterval(elementFromMousePosition, 500);
});

svg1.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  clearInterval(interval);
});

svg1.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```

```css
svg {
background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"viewBox="0 0 800 600 " id="svg1">
      <g enable-background="new">
        <path data-key="Line_1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 244.34 586.6 "/>
        <path data-key="Line_2" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 124.34 545.57 L 144.34 546.6 "/>
        <path data-key="Line_3" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 174.34 545.57 L 204.34 546.6 "/>            
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to click(from code) when hovering an element continuously by just `hover` the mouse pointer on it. I believe my piece of code will help.

We have a hover method which contains two call back methods.

1. over - fire when started hover on an element
2. out - fire when the mouse pointer is moved from that element

```
$('path').hover(
    //over
    function() {
        setInterval(function(){
            $(this).click();
        },1000) //set your time interval here
    },
    //out
    function() {
        //action after the mouse pointer is left
    }
);
```

For click and hold, try using below method as you written in your codepen demo.

I have used element `path` for adding listeners instead of document(moved those set of code inside for loop)

```
let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    paths[i].addEventListener('click', event => console.log(event.target.dataset.key));
    
    var myInterval;
    paths[i].addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        console.log("Stop");
    })
    // Keyboard keys
    paths[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        console.log("Hold ")
        myInterval = setInterval(function() {
            console.log("click..." + event.target.dataset.key)
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you mind if you implement it in my code to get it working? You can add a code snippet demo in your answer :) I believe the time interval should be about 0.1s  so that it has enough time to detect when cursor is swept faster across those svg path :)

Comment: Hi, I think you already have click event listener. Just copy this piece of code and paste inside document.ready() method. And update timer to `100` (which means 100 ms => 0.1s). Give a try and let me know if you are stuck at some point.

Comment: Hi, I have tried pasting your code into the mousedown event (When the cursor should be clicked automatically by itself when hovered over the SVG Path ), but I am really still unsure on how to solve it :). What did I do wrong? My codepen demo is here https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/LYJJLbo?editors=0010

Comment: @JamesTan I have updated the code, hope it will help you. Change the time interval to 100 ms.